# Cloning of variable in eWam

Tags: ewam

To clone an object there is a method of Motor module named ‘CloneVarsExceptFOFrom’. But if we don’t want to copy a variable or a refto of that object in the cloned object, then is there any method to do so? If no, then how is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Use Prepare clone method normally to clone.

Normally, as per the cloning concept in Wynsure, all the owned relationships of the object are cloned. Whereas, all the (P,A) relationships objects are shared.
If the developer overrides the functionality to skip some object from the cloning process, it may lead to an unexpected behavior if an owned relationship object is skipped from cloning.

In case, there is a need to implement this, it may be a good idea to revisit the data model of the existing implementation for the class in question.